# What are the different ways of saying "but"?

Tags: выбор-слова, conjunctions

I've been told that in Russian, there are at least two ways of saying "but." One is `a`, and the other is `но`. They both translate into the same word but (`a` or `но`?) they appear to have two somewhat different meanings, which is to say that they are used in different contexts. What is the difference?

Comment: You haven't listed the third variant: "but" as synonym of "except" which are mainly translated as "кроме": "nobody but him" - "никто, кроме него".

Answer (score 16):

`But` can be translated into Russian as `а` or `но`, depending on the context. `А` can be translated into English as `but` or `and`, depending on the context. Let's examine the most typical situations, without pretending that the following list is complete :)

1. The conjunction `но` contrasts actions, objects and their characteristics.

   > Я не живу в России, но хорошо говорю по-русски. I don't live in Russia, but I speak Russian well.
   >
   > Стены были деревянные, но крепкие. The walls were wooden, but strong.

   Indeed, I will agree with GSerg that in this case но has connotations of however, nonetheless.
2. The conjunction `а` is used to give a more accurate description of an object or action, rather than to contrast them.

   > Стол не стеклянный, а деревянный. The table is not made of glass, but of wood.
   >
   > Ему не десять лет, а одиннадцать. He's not ten years old, but eleven.
3. `a`, is used when one clause contradicts the other clause. `Но` is used when they simply contrast.

   > Я попросил его купить сметану, а он купил молоко. I asked him to buy sour-cream, but he bought milk.
   >
   > Они жили вместе, но не разговаривали друг с другом. They lived together, but didn't speak to each other

   Now, in the two examples above, one could replace `a` with `но` and vice versa. That wouldn't make the sentences incorrect, just a bit clumsy. It all boils down to whether you want to emphasize contrast or contradiction.
4. `a` is used as contrasting `and`, meaning whereas, while.

   > У Маши было три сестры, а у Пети четыре. Masha had three sisters, and/whereas Petya had four.
   >
   > Я живу в Италии, а мой брат в Швеции. I live in Italy, and/whereas my brother lives in Switzerland.

   In these examples you couldn't replace `а` with `и`

   > Родители уехали на дачу, а дети остались дома. The parents went to dacha, and/whereas the kids stayed home.

   In this example you could replace `a` with `но`, but the meaning would change to `but`

   > Родители уехали на дачу, но дети остались дома. The parents went to dacha, but the kids stayed home. (implies that this is somehow a surprise, a contradiction)
5. `A` is used in situations when you state something about something, and request a similar something about something else :) sort of... This meaning can be translated as `and` into English, or not translated at all.

   > Меня зовут Василий. А тебя? My name is Vasiliy. What's yours? (And what's yours?)
   >
   > Вот мой дом. А где твой? Here's my house. Where's yours? (And where's yours?)
6. `A` can be used to change the subject, meaning something like `by the way`.

   > А у нас в здании пожар был вчера. (By the way, we had a fire in our building yesterday).

   In most situations, the choice between `а`, and `но` is rather unambiguous. But, as with everything, there are certain corner cases where two conjunctions are possible, with slight, if any, differences in meaning. For example:

   > Меня попросили подождать, а я не подождал. I was asked to wait, but I didn't.
   >
   > Меня попросили подождать, но я не подождал. I was asked to wait, but I didn't.

   The first version underlines the contradiction more than the second, but there is really very slight, if any difference in meaning.

Comment: Nice answer. I would just add in part 2 that "не... а" is a common form but "не... но" is not permissible.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, "a" is quite close to "and" in this regard. "Но" has a much stronger sense of negation and confrontation with the preceding statement.

"Я спокойный человек, **но** если меня разозлят..." (I'm a calm person, **but** if somebody pisses me off...) suggests that his reaction will not be calm.

While "Я спокойный человек, **а** если меня разозлят..." (I'm a calm person, **and** if somebody pisses me off...) suggests something like "I'll reason with them and explain why they're wrong".

"Анна пошла в школу а Миша остался дома" (Anna went to school and Misha stayed home) just tells you what they did. But "Анна пошла в школу, но Миша остался дома" (Anna went to school but Misha stayed home) really emphasizes the fact that he stayed home as opposed to her.

Answer (score 4):

Word **однако** is equal to **но** (but). It gives some old-style coloration and can be used to stress this word in the sentence.

There are many other words that can be used instead of **но**: **так**, **дык** (not a formal word), **да** and many more. In some cases **но** can even be omitted.

- Хотел поспать, но не получилось.
- Хотел поспать, однако не получилось.
- Хотел поспать, так не получилось.
- Хотел поспать, дык не получилось.
- Хотел поспать, да не получилось.
- Хотел поспать, не получилось.

Answer (score 3):

`Но` generally means `however`.

`А` *(when used as "but," because `а` has lots of meanings in other contexts)* doesn't mean that, and can be used when you don't want to say "however," but do want to say there is a difference.

However, if your thought doesn't have two parts separated with "but," you want to use `но`. Using `а` as "but" requires a bit of context, and given the lack of context, it's going to be `но`. Note: the context may span several sentences. Note: the context may even be implied.
Examples of when `но` must be used, but doesn't mean "however" (because the is no context of comparing):

- When you don't know how to respond and can only repeat "But... but...".
- "But mom!.."